# "Average Daily Active Users" for Facebook API Limits

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've suddenly started running into API limits. I've been restricting my API calls to: `number of users * 200`, but I'm getting error #4 about once per day.

This calculation was based on the docs from end of 2015 that said number of users your app had yesterday, plus new logins today.

But it looks like that has changed to:

> The number of users your app has is the average daily active users of your app, plus today's new logins

Can someone explain to me what "average daily active users" is? And is there a way I can get access to this number?

---

Some information on what I'm doing:

My app fetches pages and posts from pages. To do this, I hit the Facebook API to get user's liked pages. Then each hour, I fetch posts from pages the system knows about.

I do the following:

- Batch requests (50 per batch)

  I'm only fetching posts since the last fetch (using since, until and limit params. 90% of the requests return 0 posts)

  I'm only fetching posts from pages my users like

  I'm using my app token for these requests

  I limit the number of calls per hour to users * 200

Comment: it would be a lot easier if you would tell us exactly what you are doing and how. if you hit api limits, you are most likely doing something wrong.

Comment: hi @luschn, I've added detail on what I'm doing to the question. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @MaxClarke Did you find an answer to this? I have basically the same question.

Comment: @chrisb - no, I didn't work this out accurately. Despite what luschn said, I wasn't doing anything wrong and using user tokens didn't help. In fact, in the documentation it states that the limits are the sum total of all user tokens.

I ended up simply lowering the amount per hour until it consistently worked.

Comment: OK thanks @MaxClarke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch Requests don´t reduce API limits, they are only faster, that´s all. That being said: You wrote that you are using an "App Token" for the requests - you should use a "User Token" instead. It´s still a LOT of calls though, the only thing you can do in addition is to reduce the amount of API calls.

Comment: Hmm, I understood the docs to say that it's not tied to particular users and that they add up to an app wide limit. I will try rotating through my user's tokens and see if that helps.

Comment: you want to get information for a user, so a user token would be more appropriate anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I found this endpoint in the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/

I tested this via

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<my_app_id>?access_token=<my_access_token>&fields=daily_active_users
```

And it returned

```
{
    "daily_active_users": "152",
    "id": "<my_app_id>"
}
```

It is not `average daily active users` though