# Who qualifies as "Active User" of a Facebook application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook application which recently started hitting hourly rate limit. After going through fb official documentation here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting/

I understood that if I have 100 
"users" who have authenticated my application I can make 200 * 100 = 20000 calls per hour to Facebook. Further the document says, that number of "users" is calculated as average daily "active users" of your app, plus today's new logins.

Now even after searching a lot and experimenting, I am not clear on as to who all qualifies as "active users" of fb app.

When new users authorize my application my number of "active users" rise up by the same amount, but somehow existing app users are not being counted as "active users" by Facebook even if I make graph api call on their behalf to retrieve their page's data using their own page's access token.

Please let me know if there is a way to make existing app users to be counted as "active users" as to avoid hitting by rate limits.

PS: Please note that I request for page's access token and not user's access token form my application users.

Comment: Using their Page access token should be enough. What are you doing when you get the error?

Comment: Even after making calls through users page's access token I am not able to make them to be counted as  "active users"  . I on hourly basis fetch data from fb of around 1000 fb pages of which only few are my app user, for fetching data for the rest I use pool of my app's users page's access token + my app token which is inviting rate limit error.

Comment: Why? Can't you use Webhooks instead of polling?

Comment: @PiyushMathur Did you manage to get an answer to this? We have the same question.

Comment: Would also like to know how you can calculate  how many `active users` an app has at any given moment?

Comment: @Guus see this answer for a call that returns your daily active users: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46604228/100752

Comment: @KubaHoluj hehe I created that answer myself shortly after my comment. However it does not give the `daily average active users` which is used by the algo of facebook to determine the max number of request per period an app can use. And sadly I don't have many yet so I need to apply a larger interval between each request. The only reliable info is on the app console graph, but that's useless for automation.